# Compact nowhere dense analytic closed set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

For a compact nowhere dense analytic closed set, why is that a finite set?

Can we get this set is discrete, so that it's finite?

Analytic sets are locally zero sets of holomorphic functions, which means to an analytic set $A$, to any $x\in A$, there exists a neighborhood $U_x$, s.t. $A\cap U_x=\{ y\in U_x| f_1(y)=...=f_n(y)=0\}$ for some holomorphic functions $\{f_i(x)\}$.

Comment: $A=\{ 1/n\}$ is the zero set of $f(z)=\sin(2\pi / z)$ and it doesn't contain $0$ because $f$ isn't holomorphic at $0$. For any $A \ni x $ and the corresponding $f_i$, what can $A \cap U_x$ be (point, curve, surface..) ?

Comment: @reuns your A is not closed

Comment: Sure the goal is to generalize that fact

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard definition of analytic sets as in the link below then the statement it false: the Cantor set is a Borel set in $[0,1]$, hence analytic. It is nowhere dense but not finite.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set

Comment: I think our definitions about analytic sets are different. My definition is: Analytic sets are locally zero sets of holomorphic functions, which means to an analytic set $A$, to any $x\in A$, there exists an NBHD $U_x$, s.t. $A\cap U_x=\{ x\in U_x| f_1(x)=f_2(x)=...f_n(x)\}$ for some holomorphic functions $\{f_i(x)\}$.